# Mysql alias data without selecting it

Tags: mysql

Sorry, don't know how to formulate this question. I'll try to explain. Here's a query:

```
SELECT CONCAT(uno, due, tre) AS smth ... HAVING smth LIKE ...
```

It allows me to perform operations on aggregated multi-column data and, while it works ok, i don't want the results of "smth" column to actually be selected and returned. Is it possible o do something like this?:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CONCAT(uno, due, tre) AS smth LIKE '...' OR smth LIKE '...' ...
```

Or does mysql already optimize a query with multiple identical concats to not concatinate the same data twice?

I hope the question is clear. Thank you for your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use the desired expression in the relevant `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
  -- etc.
HAVING CONCAT(uno, due, tre) LIKE '...'
    OR CONCAT(uno, due, tre) LIKE '...'
  -- etc.
```

MySQL only evaluates deterministic functions given the same arguments once per query, so despite the verbosity of the query it is no less efficient (save for a negligible amount of parsing).

Alternatively, you could perform an outer select on your query to only return the columns of interest:

```
SELECT ... FROM (
  SELECT CONCAT(uno, due, tre) AS smth ... HAVING smth LIKE ...
) t
```

Comment: It was actually a part of the same question: would this approach be optimized by database engine? Or will it have to CONCAT the same data N times, downgrading performance?

Comment: @Marius: Apologies, I missed that.  In that case, as mentioned above, yes MySQL optimizes identical concats so that it only performs the operation once.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i wanted to confirm :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, MySQL performs this optimization on any newer version.

Second you need to write

```
WHERE CONCAT(uno, due, tre)  LIKE '...'
```

without the alias - aliases are **defined** in the field list, not in the `WHERE` clause (but ofcourse you can **use** them in the where clause)

Comment: Yes, i know aliases are defined in the list :) It was just an example for people to understand what i wanted to ask :) If the optimization is performed - then the question is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to select it that should work:

```
SELECT ... WHERE CONCAT(uno, due, tre)  LIKE '...' OR smth LIKE '...' ...
```